# how to set margin value to fixed positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have applied this css on fixed position div

```
#abs{
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0; 
background-color: red; 
padding: 20px; 
width: 100%; 
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

But `margin-top: 200px;` doesn't work.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/3/)

Is there a way with jQuery?

Comment: use top only not margin-top

Comment: using top will expand the div. but i need gap between the divs. http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/8/

Comment: I need like this http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/11/ but without setting margin in #someid in the fiddle.

Comment: @C-Link Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/T5yg7/17/ ?

Comment: @Mr_Green yes, likely to the fiddle.

Comment: If that solves your problem then use it. :)

Comment: I need without setting to #someid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed positioning takes an element out of the document flow, so no fiddling the the element's margins will work. If you can't alter the html try adding

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Incidentally, if you really needed to add a bit of content to the bottom of the page, but only have access to stylesheets, you can use this:

```
body:nth-last-child(1):after {
    content: "aha ";
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DomDay/QqMFX/

Answer (score 3):

Try giving `margin-bottom:200px; for the top div class #someid` this also gives the same result
[Check This](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/12/)

**EDIT**

Add `position: relative;` instead of fixed then it will be work.

```
#abs{
     position: relative; 
     bottom: 0; background-color: red; 
     padding: 20px; 
     width: 100%;
     margin-top:200px;
    }
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/14/)

Comment: I need to set to my #abs div not to #someid.

Comment: OP titled "how to set margin value to fixed positioned div" not relative :)

Comment: crazy :) sorry i just eagerly looking for the output only :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#someid{
        position:absolute;
        height: 700px; 
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 100%;
        }
#abs{
     position:absolute;
     background-color: red;
     padding: 20px; 
     width: 100%;
     margin-top:200px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If space between `#abs` and `#someid` is your problem then have linebreaks `<br />`

Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/16/)

**Update:**
If you're open to use jquery then check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yg7/18/)

Comment: I need without touching html

Comment: Yes, likely that but without using br, is there way with css in jquery.

Comment: the updated one still using `<br />` what is the difference by adding <br /> through jquery than adding directly to html

Comment: @Nithesh First I showed him that he can solve adding br tag directly to his code.  Since he is not willing to add br tag directly, I suggested him to inject it via jQuery.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user1671639 In effect both are same na. Adding <br /> in renderd html. how it make diff